# How to add parameter in URL in CakePHP form submit?

Tags: cakephp

Please check my code:

```
<?php
    $base_url = array('controller' => 'postads', 'action' => 'search/category:sales');
    echo $this->Form->create("Filter",array('url' => $base_url, 'class' => 'filter'));
?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('minprice',array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Min','label'=>false,'value'=>100));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('maxprice',array('type'=>'text','placeholder'=>'Max','label'=>false,'value'=>200));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Go',array('type'=>'submit','label'=>false));?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end();?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function search(){
    if(($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) && isset($this->data['Filter'])){
    //pr($this->data);exit;
            foreach($this->data['Filter'] as $name => $value){   
                if($value){
                    $filter_url[$name] = urlencode($value);
                }
            }
            //return $this->redirect($filter_url);
        }
}
```

When i submit the page my URL looks like http://www.example.com/postads/search/minprice:100/maxprice:200

But i want to [http://www.example.com/postads/search/category:sales/minprice:100/maxprice:200](http://www.example.com/postads/search/category%3asales/minprice:100/maxprice:200)

Please solve my problem

Thanks
learnphp.in

Comment: $base_url = "/postads/search/category:sales" -> try this one

Comment: **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html#named-parameters** ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version and tag your question accordingly.

Answer (score -1):

You can try like this :

```
$base_url = array('controller' => 'postads', 'action' => 'search/sales/100/200');
```

in Controller :

```
public function search($category = '', $minPrice = '', $maxPrice = ''){
```

Comment: You have changed the action. But my action link is fixed with param name. I have too much field not only `category`,`minprice` and `maxprice` coding have done all the link. When i submit form the url reset and new form url is showing.

Comment: Then you can pass the array of parameters. Same way as you doing (parameterName:ParameterValue)
in controller function pass an array

    public function search($options = array())

and then get parameter name with their values and parse in query.

Comment: How to pass parameter? I am new in CakePHP

Comment: Well, I think you are making something advance search where user have to select search options. You can set Jquery code, that on submit get all fieldNames with their values and append in URL. 

in Controller you can pass an array. 

and parse that array. 

Reference of Jquery work, www.everything.pk

if you search in top bar 'zong in islamabad'

you will see the form submit link 

something like http://www.everything.pk/searches-zong_in_islamabad.html

Comment: Please check price in left side search list - http://melbourneluxurycars.com.au/listing

Comment: Yes @NaveedRamzan i am using advance search. Please check above link. :)

Comment: OK Got it, Can you check in controller -> search 

    pr($this->data);

here you will see all data submitted in GET.

I am sure it will solve your problem.

Comment: The `pr($this->data);` I am getting blank array.

Comment: Try with this : pr($this->request);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56866/discussion-between-learnphp-and-naveed-ramzan).